# How to remove carriage return in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, carriage-return

when write command on terminal it works correctly but when write command on .sh file shows an error

my command:

```
echo "hell\ro" | sed -e "s/[\]r//g"
```

test.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hell\ro" | sed -e "s/[\]r//g"
```

when execute using the command
**bash test.sh**
it shows error like this
***sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'***

sed varsion
sed (GNU sed) 4.7
Packaged by Debian

Comment: Do you want to remove actual carriage returns or the sequence backslash, lowercase R?

Comment: i want to remove carriage returns

Comment: fwiw ... *1)* OP's script works for me and does not generate any errors ... *2)* `echo "hell\ro"` generates `hell\ro` (those are the literal characters '\' and 'r' ... not a carriage return); OP may want to update the question with the output from `sed --version`, go ahead and throw in `bash --version` for good measure

Comment: You need to know the difference between `sed -e "s/[\]r//g"` and `sed -e 's/[\]r//g'` Read more [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)